# Add Event after video play is ended

Tags: javascript, video, html5-video, media-player, video.js

In Laravel project ,I have video vjs player as in this code :

```
<video
   id="my-video"
   class="video-js "
   controls 
   preload="auto"
   width="100%"
   height="auto"
   poster={{asset('images/'.$course->id.'.png')}}
   data-setup='{"fluid": true}'
   >
   <source src="{{asset('promos/'.$course->id.'.mp4')}}" />
   <source src="{{asset('promos/'.$course->id.'.mp4')}}" />
</video>
```

I want after the video end of play do and action (add data to server),I did this but don't work :

```
<script>
    var vid = document.getElementById("my-video");
    vid.onended = function() {
    alert("The video has ended");
};
</script>
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: the script is at the below of page

Comment: I used addEventListener : vid.addEventListener('ended', (event) => { action}; ,but stil don't work

Comment: I am using this : https://videojs.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Jsplayer not worked correctly I used html5 video player and it is fine:-

```
<video oncontextmenu="return false;" width="100%" height="auto" controls id="player"
controls controlsList="nodownload" poster="{{asset('images/'.$course->id.'.png')}}"
onended="alert('it is worked')">
    <source src="{{asset('promos/'.$course->id.'.mp4')}}" type="video/mp4">
    <source src="{{asset('promos/'.$course->id.'.m4v')}}" type="video/ogg">
</video>
```

Answer (score 1):

i hope that one of this is helpful

```
var options = {};
var player = videojs('my-video', options, function onPlayerReady() {
    this.on('ended', function() {
        //do something here...
    });
});
```

Ou

```
var player = document.getElementById("my-video");
player.addEventListener("ended", function() {
  //do something here...
});
```

Comment: plugin javascript for html video, you can install it via npm

Comment: is i must install it or using cdn link enough

Comment: the first code make the video don't start to play ,and second one don't work

Comment: yes u can use CDN link, and don't hesitate to read few docs on how to integrate it in your project, it's so simple

Comment: i know that's for event end, that's what are u want ?

Comment: then i have to add play event ? how ?

Comment: player.on('play', () => { });

Comment: still not work ,i read the document and tried to use useraction this.play but still not work